# mule flow http request time out tuning

Tags: mule, httprequest, mulesoft

I have a Mule flow that reads payloads from an Anypoint queue and then sends them to a REST endpoint via an HTTP request. However, I've encountered a dilemma. When I use the default timeout (30 seconds) for the HTTP request, it often times out from the REST endpoint. Yet, after increasing the timeout to 120 seconds, the messages start piling up in the Anypoint queue, causing a backlog with a single message in flight status in the queue.

Is there a recommended solution for handling this situation effectively? Thank you in advance.
BTW, I did not encouter such problem with other integration framework(e.g spring integration)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical producer consumer problem. The inbound queue is the producer. The REST endpoint is the consumer. The issue is caused by your consumer being slow to reply. 30 seconds is usually a high time for an HTTP request. Increasing the timeout and  with the endpoint slow to answer it actually compounds the problem because your flow isn't able to acknowledge the message processing is complete to the queue, causing the queue inbound to timeout in turn.

120 seconds seems excessive. If your application waits too much and accumulates requests it may eventually run out of resources to continue working. The timeout works as a failsafe to release resources earlier.

The solution is ensuring than the REST service returns in a reasonable time. That may be outside you control. You didn't provide details. You may want to adjust the timeout from the queue if possible to match. Reducing the concurrency of the flow could also help to preserve resources at the expense of potential scalability.

Comment: thanks for reply , i have two questeions 1)reducing timeout for queue, do you mean the timeout for the queue should be same value as time out of rest endpoint as 30 seconds ? 2) how to reducing the concurrency of the flow? since i could not controll speed of sending message to queue

Comment: 1) For Anypoint MQ it depends on the queue configuration and client operations/configurations. You have provided no details whatsoever in the question so I can only provide general answers. In general it would be logical that there is some logical relationship between timeouts in different parts of a process. It really depends on the requirement and maintaining logical consistency of the operations. 2) the `maxConcurrency` attribute of the flow or the connector limits how many concurrent executions can be. It could cause more timeouts though.